# Merging multiple shapefiles into one NULLs out values

Tags: qgis, merge

I am working in QGIS 3.4, and trying to merge 10 polygon shapefiles into a single shapefile.  However, the result is not preserving the values for most of the shapefiles, it's NULL-ing them out for all but one of the shapefiles.

1. Must the exact number of fields exist for all 10 shapefiles?
2. If so, must the fields be ordered exactly the same for all 10 shapefiles?
3. Must the fields be named the same for all 10 shapefiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) No, not the exact number.
2) No, order does not matter.
3) Yes, common field names & types are necessary for values to transfer from the source shapefiles into the resultant merged shapefile.

For instance:
Shape1 has a name field of NAME (text)
Shape2 has a name field of TextID (text)
Both:
Have an attribution field of EditorID (text)

When merged, the attributes/columns that are common will transfer feature/row attributes, but the attributes/columns that are unique will only transfer feature/row attributes that were originally present, marking NULL in all other attributes/columns.

The image below demonstrates this using the above example:
[image]

You can either transfer attributes to common columns ahread of the merge, or do it after the merge using the field calculator.

Comment: In this example, the field calculator expression to copy the "NAME" values into "TextID" would be `if(TextID = 0 OR TextID is NULL, NAME, TextID)`

Comment: Thank you, Saijin_Naib.  I was hoping for a quicker fix, but I just revised to match all field names, & field types/lengths exactly between shps & it worked.

Comment: Ashley, if you use Geopackage or another (not shapefile) datasource to store your data, you don't need to match lengths but merely field types & names. Can be a little bit less frustration when managing the data to be merged. Aside from that, it is almost unquestionably a superior format in every regard:
http://switchfromshapefile.org/

Answer (score 2):

With the **QGIS > Vector general > Merge vector layers** tool I recently ran into a similar issue (missing or ´NULL´ed attributes in the resulting merged layer). As a solution I recommend using the **SAGA > Vector general > Merge vector layers** tool:

[image]

It has additional options for *adding source information* and *matching fields by name*:

[image]

Comment: That's great! I never looked into that tool as I simply use the bundled QGIS Processing Algorithm, but this one is clearly better.